# spring http error 400 The request sent by the client was syntactically incorrect

Tags: java, spring, date, spring-mvc

How to resolve spring 400 error.

**My controller:**

```
@InitBinder
protected void initBinder(WebDataBinder binder) {
    SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
    binder.registerCustomEditor(Date.class, new CustomDateEditor(
            dateFormat, false));
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/admin/users/edit", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView editUser(final @ModelAttribute AdminForm form,
                             Principal principal) 

public class AdminForm {
    ...
    User newUser;
    public User getNewUser() { return newUser; }
    public void setNewUser(User newUser) { this.newUser = newUser; }
    ...
}

public class User {
...
    @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "dd/MM/yyyy")
    Date birthDate;
...
}
```

**JSP file has this input box:**

```
  <form:input
   class="tcal"
   name="date"
   itemLabel="date"
   path="newUser.birthDate"/>
```

**Browser generates this POST request:**

> newUser.fio=%D0%9F%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2+%D0%A1%D0%B8%D0%B4%D0%BE%D1%80+%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%87&newUser.login=das&newUser.password=8904&newUser.birthDate=08%2F04%2F2014&newUser.id=23

You can see that there are also other fields fio, login, password and id. If I remove birthDate, then 400 error goes away, but I need this parameter.

How can I avoid this problem?

Thanx

Comment: As `birthDate` seems correctly annotated in class User, I would not  register a custom editor for it in `initBinder`. Could you try that ?

Comment: @SergeBallesta, no this doesn't help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My problem was that in one place there was java.sql.Date and java.util.Date in another. When I changed both to java.util.Date, it worked.